# code igniter view contents of userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know what are the contents of userdata. How can I do this.

```
log_message($this->CI->session->userdata) //array
```

Comment: Do you want to show it in the php page or just have a look at it in database?

Comment: you can enable benchmarks ......in that it will automatically show the session data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the session library before checking the session data..

```
$this->load->library('session');
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Edit :

> You are not supposed to send arrays into log files... log_message() is
>   only meant to write a string .. That should be info/error/debug.. 
>   So you won't get the array in your log file..

Check [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html)

Comment: This still says that it is an array

Comment: when i print it in log_message i do not want to print it on the screen

Comment: @Rajeev You are not supposed to send arrays into log files... `log_message()` is only meant to write a string .. That should be info/error/debug.. So you won't get the array in your log file..

Comment: there is an issue when the user logs in from an android app or ios the user_id is not getting logged so i want to see the contents of the user_data in the log

Comment: @Rajeev Then use `log_message('debug',$this->CI->session->userdata('ip_address'))`... This is to check the ip_address.. You can use ip_address/session_id/user_agent/last_activity... But not the complete `userdata`

Comment: but i want to get user id rather than the ipaddress

Comment: You wont get the `user_id` unless you store it... Session data shows the above four items by default.. If you want any more data to be stored in session,set it... Use `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id)`

Comment: @Rajeev I suggest you to read the manual on codeigniter sessions so that you'll get a better idea

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) like:

```
$string = var_export($this->CI->session->userdata, TRUE)
log_message($string) // array(...)
```

It will turn the array into a string which is expected by `log_message`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to show all the userdata in the session

`print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`

Comment: or `print_r($this->session->userdata); `